# Unable to change default shell in macOS Monterey

Tags: terminal, bash

Started using Monterey.

[image]

Changed the login shell from Users&Groups to use /opt/bin/homebrew/bash.

[image]

Default shell has been changed and the computer has been restarted.

```
echo '/opt/homebrew/bin/bash' | sudo tee -a /etc/shells
chsh -s /opt/homebrew/bin/bash
```

However, when open the terminal, it is still zsh.

[image]

Please advise how to start bash 5 (/opt/homebrew/bin/bash) immediately when opening the terminal.

Comment: Are your preferences in Terminal.app set to explicitly launch a shell, rather than using your login shell setting?  This is a setting on the General tab.

Comment: When you start a window or tab from Terminal.app, the shell to be started is specified in the preferences of the app.

Comment: @user1934428 `Terminal.app` is perfectly happy to use whatever your login shell is.  You don't have to, and probably shouldn't, specify the shell in `Terminal.app` preferences.  That's really meant for starting some specific application.

Comment: @MarcWilson : That's the point: In the preferences of `Terminal.app`, you can choose whether you want to have a login shell or whether you wan to specify your own shell. This selection can be done, as you said before, in the "General" tab of the preferences. The OP wants to start explicitly bash version 5, which he installed with homebrew. So IMO this would be best configured explicitly in the preferences. This is also easier to debug, then fiddling with changes in the login shell. BTW, isn't it risky to set the default login shell to one which is not part of what Apple officially distributes?

Comment: @user1934428 Why would it be "risky"?  Be specific.

Comment: @MarcWilson: Perhaps I'm wrong here, but I thought that the shell specified as longin shell is also used by MacOS for starting various services/programs when the user logs in. In this case, using some arbitrary login shell (extreme case: csh for instance), could break this process. That's why I wouldn't fiddle around with my default login shell, but simply configure my terminal programs to use the shell I want to have.

Comment: @user1934428 Nothing risky about changing your default login shell. Mine has been set to Fish Shell for over 5+ years and never had an issue with the system doing its things in the background :)

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the Users&Groups has no effect. What is it for?

Found the way.

1. Start Terminal.
2. Open Settings and got to General.
3. Set the path to the installed bash path.

[image]

Comment: You found **a** way.  Chainging the user's default shell works as it should in Monterey, but you can do it this way too.  I'd use `dscl localhost -read /Local/Default/Users/USERNAME shell` and find out what the system thinks your default shell actually is.  `USERNAME` being whatever your login name is.